# Android Resouces Linking Failed - AAPT: error: style attribute not found

Tags: android, android-studio

**Basically New here and couldn't find the solution mostly search about everything when I build this it shows successful but when trying to run it the error comes out please share the solution if you have one.**

ERROR MESSAGE:
AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/mrl_rippleColor (aka com.oxoo.hashtag:attr/mrl_rippleColor)' not found.

These are my dependencies
dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Nobar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="RippleStyleWhite">
    <item name="mrl_rippleOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleColor">#80FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleHover">true</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleAlpha">0.2</item>
</style>


<style name="RippleStyleBlack" parent="RippleStyleWhite">
    <item name="mrl_rippleColor">#8096989A</item>
  
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium.Bold" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>

<style name="ExoMediaButton.Previous">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
<style name="ExoMediaButton.Next">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
```

Comment: have you tried to invalidate cache?

Comment: Where have you declared `mrl_rippleColor` ? Can you please share that file?

Comment: Make sure your styles.xml file is in the correct path. Just like on the answer I gave below.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your styles.xml file is in the correct path(inside `values` folder, not in `values-24` or `values-anynumberhere`). Your IDE(Android Studio) will automatically create a `styles.xml` file for supporting a customized style for different android API versions. So if the styles you defined is not in the default folder (`values` folder in your `res` folder) then copy your styles to the styles inside the values folder.

```
values
  - styles.xml
  - strings.xml
  - colors.xml
values-v24
  - styles.xml
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was style attribute 'attr/ringtonePreferenceStyle' not found. **As the error implies, just add the attribute to your values/attrs.xml file. The error will go away.**

I simply added an empty attribute like this `<attr name="ringtonePreferenceStyle"  />` which makes the error disappear and let it compile and build.

Not really sure, why it occurs but again, it is nothing something that you face or regular basis.